# Black truffle oil

Tags: substitutions

I have a new recipe that calls for 6oz of Perigord black truffles.  Since these are so expensive I ordered the black truffle oil.  How much oil should I use in place of the 6oz of truffle.

Comment: It would help to know the full recipe so we can advise. Also truffle oil will be very concentrated truffle flavor and a large percentage of the time the flavor is artificial.

Comment: Me think you need to change recipe.

Comment: 6 oz seems like a lot of truffle... unless the dish is very big, it seems like it would be a major presence in the recipe.  You might want to think about what the absence of the truffles (as physical truffles) will do to the dish, and the addition of added fat in your recipe - it might be like trying to sub apple juice for apples in a pie recipe, the recipe needs the bulk as well as flavor.  In your recipe it might help to sub in something like mushrooms to make up for the lost bulk of truffle, maybe omit some other fat to balance the truffle oil.

Comment: Try another dish...

Comment: From [this place that sells them](http://www.marxfoods.com/Fresh-French-Black-Winter-Truffles) (and presumably wants you to buy a lot and use them generously): "When figuring out how many ounces of fresh European truffles to buy, we usually recommend a serving size of 5-7 grams of fresh truffle per dish per person (that's roughly 4-5 servings per ounce)." - so 6 oz is 24-30 servings, or even more if you're not so generous? Is it really that large scale a recipe?

Comment: @Jefromi - 5-7 grams per person.  Are we sure the original recipe didn't mean 6 grams instead of 6 ounces, then, and merely mistyped the unit?  That might be a reasonable amount for a smaller scale recipe or one in which truffle is more of a supporting flavor.

Comment: @Megha Maybe! Seems a bit unlikely, since it'd be a pretty obvious (and expensive!) typo, but who can say. Just one more point in favor of always including/linking to the recipe in your questions (hint hint, Binky?).

Answer (score 1):

In general, a fresh truffle's contribution to a dish is aromatic.  I'm not saying that they don't have a flavor, but it is the aroma, hitting you in the face, that is significant.  Truffle oil is mostly made with chemically produced, artificial truffle flavor/aroma.  My chemist friends might argue that if the chemical analysis of a fresh truffle results in a compound that can be produced in a lab, they are essentially the same. Some of us would argue that something is lost in translation.  Having said that, truffles and truffle oils vary widely. Truffle oil manufacturers use various oils of various quality. In terms of the real deal, a truffle begins to lose its aroma and flavor the moment it is unearthed. So, in the end, there is no way to give you a substitution that works every time.  You'll first have to decide if you like the oil, as opposed to the real truffle.  Then, if you choose to use it, I would suggest adding a few grams at a time until you achieve results you are happy with.  For me, a real truffle is special. Once in a while, I buy the real deal from a reputable source, and enjoy.

Comment: Using a synthetic product in a food using it as a major flavor makes it a synthetically flavored food ... a lot lost in translation i'd say!